# I am using bootstrap to create a navbar but it isn't working,however other classes of bootstrap are working fine

Tags: php, html, css

I am not able to create a navbar,I tried other classes of bootstrap and they are working fine.
Please suggest something?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description"
         content="">
    <meta name="keywords"
          content="">
         
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css?v=<?php echo time(); ?>">
</head>
<body id="body">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid"> 
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
               <li class="active"><a href="">Home</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please check the documentation again.  Look at this example https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/examples/carousel/ and do a "view source" in your browser.  It shows a working nav-bar.  Also consider updating to the latest version if you are not too deep in your pages already.

Comment: @shreyanshsaxena just wondering if the answer I provided got you on the right track? If so can you mark it as correct? :)

Comment: @finiteloop I am so sorry,it just completely slipped through my mind as I got busy in that project.But your answer really helped me..Thank you so much and i am sorry.

Comment: @shreyansh saxena that is good to hear.  Will you mark the answer as correct then when you have a chance? :)

Comment: @finiteloop actually I am new to stackoverflow I don't know how to do that,I tried searching on Google but It didn't help.So if you could tell me how to do that?I am more than happy to do so :)

Comment: @shreyanshsaxena see the checkmark next to where you can upvote my answer? Click that.

Comment: @shreyanshsaxena You did not do it.  See the checkmark just below where the up and down arrows are with the 1 in between?  That's what you need to click on.

Comment: @shreyanshsaxena you did it once but you may have double clicked it cuz it still did not work.  It's gotta be green and stay green to count.

Comment: @finiteloop It's green now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double check the classes.  I was able to get it to work following the documentation here:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/

Your classes are off because I was able to use everything else in your code just fine.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="description"
             content="">
        <meta name="keywords"
              content="">
             
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css?v=<?php echo time(); ?>">
    </head>
    <body id="body">
   <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
     
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong code for Bootstrap 4.x. Your code works on bootstrap 3.x

If you want to use the latest bootstrap version's navbar, then use this.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container-fluid"> 
   <ul class="navbar-nav">
     <li class="nav-item active">
       <a href="" class="nav-link">Home</a>
     </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

For more info check [Bootstrap Navbar](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/)